# Prolog support for Vim users

Tags: vim, prolog, xsb

I am starting with Prolog programming using XSB.

What syntax highlighting script or plugin for vim editor would you suggest for (XSB) Prolog ?

Comment: What are you missing from the built-in Prolog support?

Comment: @glts, I realize now that vim has built-in syntax highlighting for prolog, which by default works on extension .pdb. I can enable it using set syntax=prolog, however it looks pretty primitive. For example, variables and constants are in the same color.

Comment: Yes, the Prolog support is quite basic. A quick search of http://www.vim.org/scripts/ produced nothing; it's possible that there are no good Prolog plugins available. (Please be aware that questions asking for tool recommendations are generally considered off-topic on Stackoverflow.)

Comment: One man's awesome syntax/scheme is another man's color hell. ;) You could (1) make sure that `vim` is selecting the `prolog.vim` file (check `:set syntax`) and you can select a color scheme to your liking. The `prolog.vim` syntax file indicates to `vim` what keywords, operators, etc, are. Between that and he color scheme, you have your `vim` style.

Answer (score 20):

Vim (7.3) comes with filetype-specific settings and syntax highlighting for Prolog. Just make sure that your file is detected as such (i.e. `:setlocal filetype?` prints `prolog`), and you have the usual `:filetype plugin on` and `:syntax on` in your `~/.vimrc`.

Vim auto-detects `*.pdb` and `*.pl` (depending on contents, can also be Perl); but you can configure additional patterns, see `:help new-filetype`.

Comment: Yes, vim 7.3 has a decent (not awesome) syntax highlighter. My `vim` autodetects `*.pl` as Perl *unless* it starts with a Prolog comment line `% ...`, then it will interpret as Prolog. It seems to default to Prolog for `.pro` files.

Comment: I am looking for awesome syntax highlighter script for vim 7.3 :)

Comment: @SourabhDaptardar haha I'm content with the vim 7.3 syntax highlighter. I just have to remember to put a `%...` comment at the top of a `*.pl` file, or it thinks it's a Perl file and it is definitely opposite of awesome. Maybe if I have time I'll tweak the syntax highlighter file (it's in the `/usr/share/vim` folder somewhere) and nudge it closer to awesome. :)

Comment: Hi @mbratch how do I get the comments syntax colors for the prolog files (*.pl) to work?, it just changing the color of the first word.

Comment: @Balz make sure the first line of your prolog file starts with a prolog comment line `% blah blah...` otherwise `vim` may think it's a Perl program.

Comment: My Vim detects *.pdb as prolog and *.pl as perl.

Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 4):

The Vim support for Logtalk is an alternative for syntax coloring of Prolog files. Given that Logtalk extends Prolog, you will get nice syntax coloring for official and de facto standard Prolog features. The latest version is available here:

https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/coding/vim

You will need to configure Vim, however, to use the Logtalk syntax highlighter support for the Prolog files (basically to recognize the file extensions that you're using for Prolog; e.g. XSB, by default, prefers `.P`). Also do try different Vim themes. Some of them are more pleasant than others.

Answer (score 2):

There are two big plugins "set" for working with Prolog in Vim:

- [adimit/prolog.vim](https://github.com/adimit/prolog.vim) - widely known but abandoned
- [soli/prolog-vim](https://github.com/soli/prolog-vim) - lesser known, but more updated and advanced

You can check files of the second - they are extending standard prolog.vim which comes with Vim, but including it. Moreover they support different flavours of Prolog - SWI Prolog, GNU Prolog, etc. You can use them as an examble and create your own.