# Swi -Prolog set the paste short cut

Tags: swi-prolog

While using the swi code editor in Ubuntu I can't seem to find a paste keyboard short cut. In windows I can paste with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. I read that sometimes it is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>, but that does not work.

Also can I turn off the auto copy when selected? I want to be able to select something to replace with paste.

I assume I need to edit the editor preferences, but I am unsure exactly how to change these? I have tried removing the leading exclamation marks.

```
! Skeleton preferences file for XPCE.  This file is loaded from       pce(Defaults).
!
! Format:
!
!   * Comment
!   Line-comment is started by the ! (exclamation mark)
!
!   * Default
!   <class>.<class-variable>: <value>
!
!   * Values
!   Values are in standard term-representation.  Chains may be written
!   as a Prolog list.  Values spanning multiple lines use \<NL> to continue
!   on the next line

! Basic style for keyboard accelerators.  On Windows the default is `cua'.
! (Common User Access), on Unix the default is `emacs'.  On Apple, the
! default is `apple', which is `emacs', but giving Command-v, Command-c
! and Command-s their usual meaning.  The Emacs equivalent can be accessed
! using ESC-v, etc.

 key_binding.style: cua
!key_binding.style: emacs
!key_binding.style: apple

! Creating a selection using  the  mouse   puts  the  selection into the
! copy/paste ! buffer by default.  This behaviour can be disabled with the
! preference below.

 editor.auto_copy:  @off
```

Comment: You could use "Vim" for prolog hightlighting too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610734/prolog-support-for-vim-users

Comment: I like the one that comes with it, just want to make a change to how it works which I assume should be possible- it looks like there are commented out lines in a setting file, but uncommenting them does not seem to change anything.

Comment: could you give the path of the settings file?

Comment: I am not sure where it lives, if I click edit , then editor preferences it brings up a file.. ill update the question to show..

Comment: Have you tried to outcomment key binding cua with ! and "incomment" key binding emacs?

Comment: Ok I have got it to work with : 

!key_binding.style: cua
key_binding.style: emacs
!key_binding.style: apple

which seems strange to me but at least it is working!

Comment: i added it as answer if it helped you

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, but unf. the (bizarre) fix suggested here doesn't work either :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong:

```
 key_binding.style: cua
!key_binding.style: emacs
!key_binding.style: apple
```

Right:

```
!key_binding.style: cua
 key_binding.style: emacs
!key_binding.style: apple
```

Maybe your keyboard layout is not recognised properly in Ubuntu.

Comment: actually, it's the other way round. `key_binding.style: cua` is right.